# Remove label borders in R Spie plot

Tags: r, plot, label

This is my code

```
require(caroline)
   x <- c(100, 90, 80, 15, 120, 25)
   y <- c(120, 120, 60, 10, 120, 15)
   names(x) <- c("Mark_1", "Mark_2", "Mark_3", "Mark_4", "Mark_5", "Mark_6")
   spie.sales <- spie(x, y,col=rainbow(length(x)),bg=c("black", "violetred1", 
                                                       "cornsilk","red", "green", "white"))
```

How do I remove the borders around the labels (Mark_1, Mark_2 etc) ?

This is the image that I get while plotting
[image]

Comment: There is no parameter, which can do it, but you can edit the function spie (`fix(spie)`) and comment `grid.rect` after the `if (pie.labs)` bit. This, however does not work for me, since R throws error `could not find function .spie`.

Answer (score 2):

Although it would be possible to use the function `fixInNamespace` to modify the `spie` function before loading the `caroline` package, I prefer to modify a copy of the function instead.

```
## Create copy of spie
spie2 <- spie
```

Also, you can maintain the option of plotting the rectangles. So a new argument, `labRects`, is added here to the new function. When the value of this object is `FALSE`, no rectangles will be plotted. When `TRUE`, the original plot is produced.

```
## Add new argument to spie2 function
formals(spie2) <- c(formals(spie), labRects = FALSE)
```

Then find what part of the function `body` needs changing and change it

```
## Assign new code into the appropriate part of the body of the function
body(spie2)[[9]][[4]][[8]][[3]][[2]] <- substitute({
    if(labRects) {
        grid.rect(x = cos(angleAnn) * maxx, y = sin(angleAnn) * maxx, 
            width = 1.5 * stringWidth(x$namesSlices[i]), height = 1.5 * 
            stringHeight(x$namesSlices[i]), default.units = "native", 
            gp = gpar(col = col[i], fill = "white", lwd = 2))
    }
})
```

Because, as Zbynek notes, the `spie` function and the new `spie2` function both rely on the non-exported `.spie` function from the `"caroline"` package, we need to change the environment of `spie2` to match that of `spie` to allow access to the `.spie` function.

```
## Change environment of spie2 to "caroline"
environment(spie2) <- environment(spie)

## ...and plot
spie.sales <- spie2(x, y,col=rainbow(length(x)),
  bg=c("black", "violetred1", "cornsilk","red", "green", "white"),
  labRects = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks BenBarnes and Zbynek! The solution worked fine