# Is it possible to get multiple spie charts on one page with R?

Tags: r, layout, plot

I did some graphs with the `spie()` function and now I would like them on one page. I know how to use the `layout()` function to split the page into enough rows and columns. But always when I then run a `spie()` function, the spie chart is not in a "matrix scheme" but over the whole page? Any ideas why this is like this?

Below my code:

```
require(caroline) # edited

par(mar=c(3,3,3,3))
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 4, 2, byrow = FALSE))

p1=c(0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09,0.09) 
p2=c(4, 16, 17, 11, 10, 16, 6, 9, 18, 1, 11) 
spie(p1,p2, bg="white", grid=FALSE, p1.circle=FALSE, pie.labs=FALSE,
     col=c("red", "darkorange", "yellow", "olivedrab2", "limegreen",
           "aquamarine", "royalblue1", "mediumblue", "slateblue3",
           "hotpink", "mediumvioletred"))
```

Comment: From which package `spie` comes from? Anyway, instead of `layout`, try `par(mfrow=c(4,2))` and see if it works.

Comment: @nicola: I edited the question to include the package caroline, based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374097/remove-label-borders-in-r-spie-plot

Comment: This is using `grid` graphics so yes it's possible but not with `par`

Comment: @TylerRinker what function do I have to use then?